# c++ managed class constructor can not have parameters?

Tags: managed-c++

please help me out , why my code cannot compile,
the compiler complains that:
error C2629: 意外的“StringToAnsi (”
error C2334: “{”的前面有意外标记；跳过明显的函数体
error C2629: 意外的“StringToAnsi (”
...
Here is my code:

```
#using <System.dll>
#using <mscorlib.dll>
class StringToAnsi
{
private:
    void * m_ptr;
public:
    StringToAnsi( System::Object ^ str)
    {
           m_ptr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(safe_cast<System::String^>(str)).ToPointer();
    }
    StringToAnsi(System::String ^ str)
    {
        m_ptr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer();

    }
    ~StringToAnsi()
    {
        System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeHGlobal(System::IntPtr(m_ptr));
    }
    operator const ACHAR*()
    {
        return (const ACHAR*)m_ptr;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to translate the error messages, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what 的前面有意外标记 means :S

Comment: sorry to every one here, I'm using vc7.0 and write mixed code for the first time, the pointer is * but not ^, that's it

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two constructors with the same number of parameters. There is an Object and a String, but both are an Object. So this seems very ambiguous.

When you create two methods (or constructors), you can't let them have the same number of parameters, because the compiler doesn't know which one to call.

When you put in a string into the construction like so: `new StringToAnsi("bla")`. The compiler doesn't know which constructor to use.